# Implement RMI thread dispatch policy

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

I'm implementing in Java a server for an Android game using RMI.
I found out I can't handle thread dispatching with any RMI class method.
Is there a workaround to implement a thread dispatch policy still using RMI?

Thank you.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Android even supported RMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found out I can't handle thread dispatching with any RMI class method

I don't know what this means. You can implement any thread despatch policy you like. RMI doesn't stop you.

However RMI already has its *own* thread despatching, for mapping incoming invocations to server threads, which you can't mess with, so you may not need your own at all.